# Algorithm for testing Fermat number divisors

Tags: number-theory

The other day, I noticed a pattern within the factors of [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) from which I developed an algorithm that can quickly determine whether a number 'n' divides any Fermat number (not a specific Fermat number, any Fermat number):

```
bool IsFermatNumberFactor(int n)
{
    int s = 4;
    int m = n;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        s = s * s % m;
        n /= 2;
    }

    if (s == 1)
    {
        // 'n' is a (composite or prime) factor of some Fermat number.
        return true;
    }
    else 
    {
        // 'n' does not divide any Fermat number.
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am wondering if it is anything new, as I could not find it in a cursory web search. It does, however, seem to be very closely related to the [Lucas-Lehmar test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) for Mersenne primes, and I think a similar proof could be given. I can explain a bit more about how it works, if necessary.

This algorithm can also be adjusted to test for factors of generalized Fermat numbers as well, and even factors of Mersenne numbers. I can share all that if people are interested.

**Edit**: As pointed out by [Gerhard Paseman](https://mathoverflow.net/users/3402/gerhard-paseman), this algorithm does seem to report 'true' for some numbers which are not factors of Fermat numbers. I believe that all of these 'false positives' are the set of squarefree composite numbers whose factors are all Fermat primes or factors of Fermat numbers, e.g. 15 (3*5), 85 (5*17).

For reference, here are all n <= 100000 for which the above algorithm returns 'true':

3,5,15,17,51,85,255,257,641,771,1285,1923,3205,3855,4369,9615,10897,13107,21845,32691,54485,65535,65537

And with filtering out known Fermat number factors: 3,5,17,257,641,65537 (See: [A023394](https://oeis.org/A023394) for additional terms).

Comment: Unfortunately, this will report 15 as a factor of a Fermat number.  15 is not a factor of any Fermat number. Gerhard "Back To The Editing Screen" Paseman, 2019.03.11.

Comment: Indeed you are correct. I neglected to mention this in my post, but I believe it also reports 'true' for squarefree composite numbers whose factors are all Fermat primes or factors of Fermat numbers, e.g. 15 (3*5), 85 (5*17).

Comment: The problem is you are actually finding factors of F_n -2, which are products of all the smaller Fermat numbers.  You will thus report numbers which are products of such factors as being factors of a Fermat number, which will be a false positive. (Also, square freeness is not guaranteed.)  I am not finding this algorithm novel.  Gerhard "Maybe Show The Generalization Instead" Paseman, 2019.03.11.

Comment: Interesting, I did not make the F_n-2 connection.  I have not studied Fermat numbers very much, so thank you for that (I actually stumbled upon this while researching something entirely).  If you filter out known factors and throw in some GCD computations, could this be a useful method for finding factors?  I apologize for being so vague -- I can post more details tomorrow.  I didn't want to try and prove something which was already known :P

Comment: I recommend you post the more general version on math.stackexchange.  The audience there has some competent readers and if they have an interest, they may tell you some more. I want to encourage your desire to pursue this and discover more, but I don't think MathOverflow is the right forum for this question.  Even better would be to visit mersenne.org and check out the info they have.  I suspect there is some basic theory they have that you may want to pursue.  Gerhard "Also Check Out Zsigmondy's Theorem" Paseman, 2019.03.11.

Comment: This algorithm checks whether the order of 2 modulo $n$ is a power of 2. For primes this is equivalent to checking whether $n$ divides some Fermat number.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta that is what I suspected it was doing, so thank you for confirming. Is there a known algorithm for this that runs in polynomial time?  As far as I know, finding the multiplicative order of a number requires its full factorization.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Thank you for your words of encouragement and for your help. I will try posting on mersenne.org as well as posting a more generalized version here (with some actual maths).